# Netbeans - custom shortcut to create HTML elements

Tags: php, html, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been trying out Netbeans PHP stuff lately, over from Webuilder.  In Webuilder, SHIFT+ENTER will make a `<br />` element, while SHIFT+SPACE will make a `&nbsp;`.

Turns out this is really handy and I miss it in Netbeans.  Is there a way to get this functionality somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to click on `Edit -> Start Macro Recording` then you have to type in `<br />` and afterwards click on `Edit -> Stop Macro Recording`. In the next window you can assign a name and shortcut to your Macro

Edit:
And remove to shortcut for `Start new Line` in `Tools -> Options -> Keymap` because it is interfering

Comment: Boom that did it.  Cheers! And +1 for the "remove" part, since that's also in the solution.  My opinion of Netbeans has climbed up another notch.

Answer (score 5):

The Code Templates feature might also be useful (especially for bigger chunks of code, like a class definition):

> Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates

Comment: +1 for the new idea - it is interesting, but unfortunately doesn't solve the original question.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You can create macros, and assign a shortcut to the macro.